# Formulate an UPDATE..SET with reference to table which is updated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to make an update as follows:

```
Update Table_A As a
set COLUMN_1=
     (SELECT COLUMN_4 From TABLE_B as b
      WHERE b.COLUMN_2 = a.COLUMN_3)
```

but I cannot use "As" in the "UPDATE" line. So how can I do this type of update?

EDIT:
Using the inner join I get the error "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value." when assigning a date value to a date value?! Do Null Values cause this trouble? 
Using IsDate() only the null Values are non-date values in the source column.

EDIT2:

```
Update a
set a.COLUMN_1 = b.COLUMN_4
from Table_A as a
inner join TABLE_B as b on b.COLUMN_2 = a.COLUMN_3
where b.COLUMN_5=17 and c.COLUMN_6 is not null
```

Comment: Check the exact columns that cause the error. You probably forgot to convert one of the columns either in the SET instruction or in the JOIN.
Ex. set COLUMN_1 = CAST(COLUMN_4 AS DATE)

Comment: It is not a cast. Both COLUMNS (Src and Dst) have type date.....
excluding the Null values does not work either (where isnull(COLUMN_SRC,'+') = '+')

Comment: Can you post a more recent version of your statement with anonymous column names?

Comment: COLUMN_1 is of type date? Also, what are the types of COLUMN_2 and COLUMN_3 ?

Comment: COLUMN_1 is date, yes.  COLUMN_2 and 3 are fine, bacause no error occurs when I use other columns for 1 and 4.

Comment: Than it must be your Column_4. Try:
UPDATE a
SET COLUMN_1 = CAST(b.COLUMN_4 AS DATE)
FROM Table_A AS a
INNER JOIN TABLE_B AS b
ON b.COLUMN_2 = a.COLUMN_3

Comment: COLUMN_4 is DATE as well. Using the CAST I get the same error.

Comment: Column_4 must be of type varchar, else you would not get the error. What is the format of Column_4, when you only select the table_b? You can also try to add WHERE ISDATE(Column_4) = 1  but the error is mostly thrown before the where conditions are evaluated. It seems to be a data specific problem.

Comment: Select distinct COLUMN_4 from TABLE_B 
    where isDate(COLUMN_4) = 0

shows only NULL as a result.

Comment: IsDate is not always reliable. Check the difference between DATE, DATETIME and DATETIME2 as your error suggests it tries to implicit convert to a datetime. Analyze your source data, is the format mm/dd/yy, m-d-y, dd.mm.yyyy or is it even mixed? Does it contain hour and minute precision, because that will fail your conversion from char to date. Dont mix up different questions in one thread. Your issues with data conversion is not easy to fix without knowing your actuall data. Read http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just join the tables with the corresponding values and use the alias to refer what table you want to update:

```
UPDATE a
SET COLUMN_1 = b.COLUMN_4
FROM Table_A AS a
INNER JOIN TABLE_B AS b
ON b.COLUMN_2 = a.COLUMN_3
```

Comment: It's a basic update statement. Yet I was 11 sec faster =P

Comment: Because we are both right. Points to go @RaulSebastian. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Update a
set a.COLUMN_1 = b.COLUMN_4
from Table_A as a
inner join TABLE_B as b on b.COLUMN_2 = a.COLUMN_3
```

Noel

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the sub query at any cost, then instead of aliasing you should use the table name itself in the query in this query.
The query in the question here will be translated into as

```
Update Table_A
set COLUMN_1=
              (SELECT COLUMN_4 From TABLE_B as b
               WEHERE b.COLUMN_2 = Table_A.COLUMN_3)
```